# Replace chair straw with cat-resistant material?

Tags: cats, furniture

I have a rocking chair that looks like the picture below, but without the nice straw backing.

Unfortunately, my cats literally destroyed the straw, so I would like to replace it with some material that's cat-proof or cat-resistant.

What do you recommend?

[image]

Replace rocking chair straw with cat-resistant material?

Comment: I'm afraid this question might be off-topic for Pets.SE. The actual (on topic) question would be how to stop your cats from destroying the chair once it's repaired. That directly leads to my next question: Do you offer your cats a scratching post or some other dedicated object where they can sharpen their claws? Scratching is part of the natural behavior of cats and you absolutely cannot stop them from it. If you don't have a scratching post, they'll scratch your furniture or walls instead.

Comment: Any [sufficiently cat-proof material](https://www.metalsdepot.com/steel-products/steel-expanded-metal?gclid=CjwKCAjw4NrpBRBsEiwAUcLcDDiUO_1QK0U5ufTa_DRgs0oUMPfz6YKf6-YoU5otlx7k_SSlAd5M-hoCpn4QAvD_BwE) would probably not be comfortable to sit on or lean against. Redirecting their attention elsewhere would definitely be the way to go.

Comment: For materials I would advise asking on https://diy.stackexchange.com/ Home Improvement :)